API fetch glaccount data from Maximo
I am using the Postman API to fetch data from Maximo.
I created an object structure by which I was fetching the data before, but for this particular work, I have to pull in data from two different objects under same object structure and then display it using the API.
Below is the SQL query equivalent for the API:
Select \* from glcomponents where compvalue IN (SELECT GLCOMP02 FROM CHARTOFACCOUNTS WHERE GLCOMP01 ='CM..') and orgid ='0001' and sapglaccttype ='A'
GLCOMPONENTS, CHARTOFACCOUNTS are objects under GMI_MSP_GL object structure
I have been trying to run the below API, but it seems to not work (https://serverhost/maxrest/oslc/os/GMI_MSP_GL?lean=1&oslc.select=compvalue,comptext&oslc.where=compvalue="CM.." and orgid="0001" and sapglaccttype ="A")
I am expecting the SQL result from the API fetch.
